# Is it possible to save and restore the Arduino IDE "Tools" settings somehow?

Tags: arduino-ide

I'm using quite a few different types of microcontrollers with the Arduino IDE (v 1.8.19). Several AVR-based boards, but also ESP32 and Arduino Due. Particularly the newer boards have a quite long set of options in the tool menu, as seen in this screen shot (for an ESP32-Dev module).

[image: List of menu options]

Each time I swap boards, the settings revert back to defaults and I have to remember updating them according to my needs. Is there a way to save the current IDE configuration, so that I can easily load all the settings I need for e.g. "ESP32"? When I haven't used a certain board for some time, I often even fail to remember exactly what settings I needed.

Comment: I didn't find a way

Comment: @Juraj Thanks for trying. Maybe someone knows a way to backup a settings file or something. Because at least the IDE remembers the last settings.

Comment: even the IDE 2 doesn't have it. only the WebEditor and CLI have it https://arduino.github.io/arduino-cli/0.28/sketch-specification/#sketchjson

Comment: IDE remembers the settings in global preferences.txt with many other IDE settings

Comment: a workaround could be to define own board in boards.local.txt with all the settings predefined

Comment: One of the many reasons people switch to VS Code + platformIO plugin for Arduino programming. It configures the setting on each project with platformio.ini file.